# Use of word `Descriptor` when naming class

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, descriptor

I am finding this rather difficult to explain, so I shall start with a little context. The examples in brackets are oversimplified but should be enough to get my intention across.

- There are 6 kinds of brush class (i.e. Pencil, Pen)
- There can be countless instances of each of those 6 brush classes where each instance defines a specific brush (i.e. HB Pencil, B8 Pencil)

I would like to create a descriptor class that describes each of the 6 brush kinds. This class will include the `System.Type` of the brush class, the `System.Type` of the brush editor class along with some more advanced stuff.

Should my class be called `BrushDescriptor` or `BrushKindDescriptor`?

I want to clarify that the descriptor describes the `Pencil` class itself and not the `HB Pencil` object.

Comment: Having `Kind` and `Descriptor` sounds like something from the *Department of Redundancy Department*.  I don't see anything wrong with BrushDescriptor.

Comment: My suggestion is to just hit up good ole http://www.classnamer.com/ and keep refreshing until something sounds good.

Comment: @EricJ. I had similar thoughts however I was concerned that people would take `BrushDescriptor` as the description of a brush as opposed to a kind of brush.

@Marc Lol

I see that my question has been voted down. I think that this is a perfectly reasonable question. Naming conventions are important and I was unclear in this case.

Comment: @LeaHayes, wasn't me, I was just having fun with the link. Love that site. Have a +1, I think naming is too often disregarded and is supremely important to development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I don't think *descriptor* or *kind* are the right words here; but first the answer.

The class should be called `BrushDescriptor` as BrushKindDescriptor is a tautology and doesn't add anything.

However as *descriptor* really means to describe or identify - and you're not really doing this you are building a class that will allow a specific type of brush to be defined, so the word should be *definition*.

If you said "6 brush definitions" instead of  "6 kinds of brush class" I think it's better English makes it clearer and thusly maybe you should be using `BrushDefinition` instead.